# java, How can I show a list when choose a item in the combobox(GUI)?

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox

I have a doubly linkedlist that contains `"Drivers","Tickets","Buses","Passengers"` info and I want to print if I choose a item in the combobox for example when I pick `driverlist`, use my print method to print the information, if its any way to show each list by a chooser, please tell me, thanks.

```
 private static void Listframe() {
     JFrame f = new JFrame("Lists");
     String Lists[]={"Drivers","Tickets","Buses","Passengers"};
     JComboBox box = new JComboBox(Lists);
     JButton b = new JButton("show");

     JLabel label = new JLabel();
     f.setTitle("Lists");
     f.setForeground(Color.white);
     f.setBackground(Color.black);
     f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
     f.setSize(new Dimension(600,500));
     f.setLocation(new Point(20, 50));           
     f.setVisible(true);
     f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
     f.add(box);
     f.add(label);
     f.add(b);
     b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             String data = "picked list for: " + box.getItemAt(box.getSelectedIndex());  
             label.setText(data);
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the linked list as well please?

Comment: @JulesDupont https://ufile.io/q1ga0 this is my uncomplete method with linkedlist